# How to implement search form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have asked this question before but i did not get the right answer. I have a table 'cv', i want to search for items in the database using two fields i.e. course and location, the two items are on the same table('cv'). I dont have an idea on how to implement the two searches. 
The code below is for displaying search for course only and its working fine. Help me to use the two search criterions i.e.course and location or in other words how do i add the search for location input in my code.

Controller

```
function search_worker()
{
    $data['query']=$this->kint_model->search_workers($this->input->post('search'));
    $this->load->view('hire_display',$data);
}
```

Model

```
function search_workers($search)
{
    return $query = $this->db->get_where('cv', array('course '=> $search))->result();
}
```

View

```
$data = array('name'=>'search', 'id'=>'search','value'=>'bcom');
    echo form_input($data);

    $data = array('name'=>'submit', 'id'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Search Item(s)');
    echo form_submit($data);
```

Comment: Please clearify your question, or learn some basic SQL. What you are looking for is the JOIN and some WHERE commands. 
Is your second search in the same Table? Give the scheme to clearify.

Comment: the two items are on the same table

Comment: then change query to ....get_where('cv', array('course' => $searchCourse, 'location' => $searchLocation))->result()...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a like clause in  your query,

```
function search_workers($search){
    //return $query = $this->db->get_where('cv', array('course '=> $search))->result();
    return $this->db->like('course', $search)->like('location', $location)->get('cv')->result();
}
```

You should also get some basic SQL training.